# Inequalities and arithmetic operations

Tags: inequality

I'm reading a paper with some math involved, and on a demonstration the author makes this assumptions:

$a/b < e/f$   and   $c/d < e/f$

And after that and without stating anything else it concludes the following:

$f(a + c) < (b + d)e$

Is that a valid conclusion from the premise, or maybe the author forgot to mention additional statements? Sorry about the basic question, but it has been a long time since I reviewed basic math.

Comment: Are you sure you copied that correctly? As written above, you have $e/f < c/d < e/f$, which would seem to imply that $e/f = c/d$.

Comment: @msteve that might have been my doing...I was editing the copy-and-paste block text and there was a floating carat

Comment: I just corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is only a valid conclusion if $bf$ and $df$ are non-negative.

If $bf,df\ge 0$, then $af<be$ and $cf<de$, so $f(a+c)=fa+fc<be+fc<be+de=(b+d)e$.